# DGESV gives wrong solution?

Tags: matlab, fortran, linear-algebra

all. I'm trying to solve a Ax=B system in fortran by calling DGESV from lapack.
where,

A =[

```
 1     0     1     0     1     0     1
 0     1     0     1     0     1     0
 0     0     4     0    32     0   108
 0     0     0    24     0   120     0
 0     0     0     0    48     0   192
 0     0     0     0     0    80     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0   120]
```

B=[
     0
     0
     2
     6
     0
     0
     0]

x can be simply calculated in Matlab by x=A\B, which gives
x =

-0.5000
   -0.2500
    0.5000
    0.2500
         0
         0
         0

while I doing the same thing in Fortran, it gives me totally different values. Is there anything wrong with my code or I just make errors in calling DGESV?
Here is my fortran code:

```
  program GG
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: N=7
  integer :: i,j,ipiv(N),ok
  real(8), dimension(1:N,1:N) :: M
  real(8), dimension(1,1:N) :: b


  M(:,1)=(/1.,0.,1.,0.,1.,0.,1./)*1.d0
  M(:,2)=(/0.,1.,0.,1.,0.,1.,0./)*1.d0
  M(:,3)=(/0.,0.,2.**3/2,0.,4.**3/2,0.,6.**3/2/)*1.d0
  M(:,4)=(/0.,0.,0.,3.*(3.**2-1.),0.,5.*(5.**2-1.),0./)*1.d0
  M(:,5)=(/0.,0.,0.,0.,4.*(4.**2-2.**2),0.,6.*(6.**2-2.**2)/)*1.d0
  M(:,6)=(/0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,5.*(5.**2-3.**2),0./)*1.d0
  M(:,7)=(/0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,6.*(6.**2-4.**2)/)*1.d0

  b=reshape((/0,0,2,6,0,0,0/)*1.d0,shape(b))


  call DGESV(N,1,M,N,ipiv,b,N,ok)
  write(*,*), b

  end program GG
```

the results given by this code is:

0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000       0.50000000000000000       0.25000000000000000      -0.33333333333333337      -0.37500000000000000        8.3333333333333315E-002

thanks, sincerely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix you are creating in Fortran appears to be the transpose (rows and columns flipped) of the one you define in MATLAB. Note (in MATLAB):

```
>> A = [1     0     1     0     1     0     1
        0     1     0     1     0     1     0
        0     0     4     0    32     0   108
        0     0     0    24     0   120     0
        0     0     0     0    48     0   192
        0     0     0     0     0    80     0
        0     0     0     0     0     0   120];
>> B = [0 0 2 6 0 0 0];
>> x = A\B.'
x =
   -0.5000
   -0.2500
    0.5000
    0.2500
         0
         0
         0
>> x = (A.')\B.'  % A is transposed, and you get your Fortran result
x =
         0
         0
    0.5000
    0.2500
   -0.3333
   -0.3750
    0.0833
```

In other words, doing `M(:,1)=...` in Fortran fills the first **column**, not the first **row**. If you flip them to `M(1,:)=...` and so forth, I think it should match the results from MATLAB.

Comment: Wow, I didn't notice that. Thank you so much